# Are associations necessary in both model and table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm rather new to RoR and have been going through [the associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) provided at rubyonrails.org.

I've noticed though in each example, when it gives what "the corresponding migration might look like", they've included the association in the migration table.

I've been including associations in my models, is it necessary for me to add them within the migration tables to? Or is the guide providing this to help readers understand the association?

For the record, I do understand if an association is made between two objects, each object model needs to have an id to associate with.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kristian,

Associations can get a little confusing.

You only need to add them in your models. For example if I have a post model with a user.

Post.rb (model)

```
belongs_to :users
```

User.rb

```
has_many :posts
```

Here is a link that may help you

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-models.html

Here is a railscast video that might help:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association?view=asciicast

PS: You do not need to add them to migrations. Migrations are there to rebuild the database if you need to restart or rollback

Comment: @KristianBouw Just to add a bit of extra info, foreign key integrity is ultimately handled in the model as per the Rails / Active Record philosophy of treating the database as a "dumb" storage. If you haven't see it already, check out this part of the Active Record Migrations guide about [referential integrity](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#active-record-and-referential-integrity).

Comment: Keep going with rails, it's frustrating at times but soon you'll be able to turn round and answer questions on here that you didn't understand 2 months ago.